# Xamarin.Android: Save a Image permanently like a profile picture with Shared Preferences

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

In my Xamarin.Android app I want something like a cover picture, that would be saved at the first start of the app. The user can change it by clicking on an example picture.

So far so good, but when I close the app and start it again the picture isn't showing.

I got the picture from `Android.Net.Uri` but how to set it to `SharedPreferences` and how can I show it in `OnCreate()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store image uri to the Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key_uri", "uri_value");
editor.commit();
```

after storing it when you open the app in onCreate() check for this string

```
SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
String image_uri= settings.getString("key_uri", "null");
```

then convert the image_uri which is a string into Uri

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(image_uri);
```

then use this image_uri to place and show as an image.

Comment: But how can I get the Uri back?
You are converting it to String, but I want it as an Uri

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot directly store the image in shared prefs. you can either store the image's absolute path in the storage or url of the image or convert the image bitmap to byte array and store the byte array(string) in shared prefs.

here are two alternatives.

- Store the absolute path or URI

  ```
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("isSetImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString("isSet", "true");
      editor.putString("absolutePath",filePath);
      editor.commit();
  ```

  you have to give the absolute path or the URI in 'filepath'
- ByteArray converted to base64

Write Method to encode your bitmap into string base64 and return the base64 string from the bitmap

```
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("isSetImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("isSet", "true");
        editor.putString("absolutePath",BitmapToBase64(mBitmap));
        editor.commit();
```

to check if the image is set or not:

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("isSetImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String isSet = sharedPreferences1.getString("isSet", "");
    String absPath = sharedPreferences1.getString("absolutePath", "");
    if(isSet.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {
        if(absPath!=null){
            previewMedia(absPath);
        }
    }
```

Note: this is code from one of my android studio project. There wont be difficult to use as Xamarin.Android

happy Coding   \,,/